# How can I access this Flask global from AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, python, angularjs, flask

I am building a internal web app with Flask that connects to various clusters. 95% of the URLs start with /cluster/cluster_name so I use the following code in my blueprints:

```
cluster = Blueprint('cluster', __name__, url_prefix='/cluster/<cluster_name>')

@cluster.url_defaults
def add_cluster_name(endpoint, values):
    values.setdefault('cluster_name', g.cluster_name)

@cluster.url_value_preprocessor
def pull_cluster_name(endpoint, values):
    g.cluster_name = values.pop('cluster_name')
```

Which then allows me to use the following code to create a connection to the cluster before each request:

```
@app.before_request
    def before_request():
        if not hasattr(g, 'manager'):
            g.manager = ClusterInterface(g.cluster_name)
```

This works perfectly and allows me to use {{ g.cluster_name }} in jinja2 templates.

The problem is that I am moving to an AngularJS app for the frontend so I won't be using jinja2 templates/render_template() anymore.

So how can I have this global available to AngularJS templates without returning its value from every Flask views?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your views will now send JSON data instead of rendered HTML templates in order to communicate with Angular.  So make this data available in the JSON response.

```
return jsonify(cluster_name=g.cluster_name)
```

More likely, you should just send the default and available names when you first start the Angular app, and let it handle the value on it's end.

Sending `g.manager` is impossible, since it's a Python object with (probably) complex behavior, not something that is JSON serializable.